# "Connect" my personal website to wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I used to have a blog on wordpress.com, now I've created my own site (using wordpress of course), on a privately hosted domain. I used to have a lot more traffic hitting my blog on wordpress.com than on my new site.

I can see some other sites (not subdomains on wordpress.com) listed in "freshly pressed" rss feed.

How can I do that on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured that this can be done with an [Offsite Redirect](http://en.support.wordpress.com/offsite-redirect/) upgrade.

It's a paid service (12$ per year), so I won't try it for now, however, for the sake of stackexchange Q/A, I would like to get a comment from someone who actually used this.